# UIWebview does not display embedded youtube well for iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, ios8

I have difficulty to play embed youtube in UIWebview.

If I used the default embed format from youtube, it does not show anything in the UIWebview. Just blank.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><body><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/XNnaxGFO18o?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

I googled around and found the following code works.

```
NSString* embedHTML = @"\
<html><body style=\"margin:0;\">\
<<div class=\"emvideo emvideo-video emvideo-youtube\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/bPM8LKYMcXs?hd=1\" width=\"320\" height=\"250\"></embed></div>\
</body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

However, there is a problem. If I click the play button, it has no response. I have to click the play button a couple of times and wait a while, then it starts to spin and then play.

So I have two questions.

1) Do you have a better way to play embed youtube video in UIWebView?
2) How to play the video instantly after you click the play button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

create a plain `html` file  and name it as `youtubeEmbedding.html` and add it to your project in the youtubeEmbedding.html just add the below code to `.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api';

        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        firstScriptTag.requestFullScreen();
        var ytplayer = null;

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() 
        {
            ytplayer = new YT.Player(
                                     'player',
                                     {
                                     videoId:'%@',
                                     width:'%0.0f',
                                     height:'%0.0f', %@
                                     playerVars:
                                     {
                                     'controls': %d,
                                     'playsinline' : 0,
                                     'rel':0,
                                     'showinfo':0
                                     },
                                     });
        }


    function onPlayerReady(event)
    {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function stopVideo()
    {
        if (ytplayer)
        {
            ytplayer.stopVideo();
            ytplayer.clearVideo();
        }
        return 'STOPPED';
    }

    function playVideo()
    {
        if (ytplayer)
        {
            ytplayer.playVideo();
        }
        return 'PLAY';
    }

    function pauseVideo()
    {
        if (ytplayer)
        {
            ytplayer.pauseVideo();
            ytplayer.clearVideo();
        }
        return 'PAUSED';
    }

    function getPlayerState()
    {
        return ytplayer.getPlayerState();
    }

    function isPlaying()
    {
        return (myPlayerState == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING);
    }
    function isPaused()
    {
        return (myPlayerState == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED);
    }
    function onPlayerError(event)
    {
        alert("Error");
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

and in the controller where u are using web view just do like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   BOOL autoPlay = NO;
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   NSString *youTubeVideoHTML  = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youtubeEmbedding" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   NSString *autoPlayString    =  autoPlay ? @"events: {'onReady' : onPlayerReady }," : @""; //customise it weather u want to autoplay or not
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYo72E7ZMHM"];
   NSString *lastComponent = [url query];
   NSString *videoId   = [lastComponent  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"v=" withString:@""]; //get  the video id from url
   NSInteger controls  = 1; //i want to show controles for play,pause,fullscreen ... etc
   NSString *html      = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, videoId, CGRectGetWidth(_webView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_webView.frame), autoPlayString, controls]; //setting the youtube video width and height to fill entire the web view 
  _webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
  _webView.delegate = self; //not needed
  [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]]; //load it to webview

}


//for playing action 
- (IBAction)playAction:(id)sender 
{
  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"ytplayer.playVideo()"];
}
```

comment if u hav any problem, hope this helps u .. :)

Comment: Strange, the uiwebview is blank. I printed out html, it has correct content.

Comment: @user890207 test it in new project

Comment: Yes. It is strange. Since yesterday, even my old code worked well. It seems Google has made some changes. Thanks!