# Hide controls youtube API it's difficult

Tags: objective-c, video, youtube, youtube-api

I've been trying to do this but I can't make in possible I checked all the possible methods that could help me but nothing works, what I'm trying to do is to play a video using the youtube API and I have to play that video but without controls because it suppose that the user cannot pause forward or reward the video but I still can't do this, as you know the YTPlayerView is the class that the API provides to us, inside this class are the methods declared, so I'll let you what I have inside this class and my class where my viewController is connected to do the task. Hope you can help me. Thanks

```
VideoViewController 
#import "VideoViewController.h"

@interface VideoViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.playerView.delegate = self;
    NSDictionary *playerVars = @{ @"controls" : @0 };
    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId: @"M7lc1UVf-VE" playerVars: playerVars];
}
-(void)playerViewDidBecomeReady:(YTPlayerView *)playerView{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Playback started" object:self];
    [self.playerView playVideo];
}


@end




YTPlayerView.m

- (BOOL)loadWithVideoId:(NSString *)videoId playerVars:(NSDictionary *)playerVars {
  if (!playerVars) {
      playerVars = @{@"controls" : @0
                     };
  }
  NSDictionary *playerParams = @{ @"videoId" : videoId, @"playerVars" : playerVars };
  return [self loadWithPlayerParams:playerParams];
}
```

Comment: You may want to use the [library](https://github.com/JV17/YoutubePlayer) as presented in a related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26923332/5995040) as a workaround for the [YouTube Helper Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper). Simple implementation and code samples are there in the library. Hope this helps.